# Создание уникальных пользователей IMAP

Tags: php, email, ssh, shell, imap

Добрый день! Как средствами PHP организовать регистрацию новых учетных записей IMAP (уникальных email адресов) на своем IMAP сервере? Эти адреса в дальнейшем будут переданы пользователям, на них будет приходить информация для обработки.

Как полученные таким образом письма переадресовывать на один ящик, с сохранением адреса первоначального получения?

Comment: в моем понимании задача сводится к написанию строки коротая регистрирует нового пользователя электронной почты на сервере, эту строку передаем функции system('тут код', $retval);

Comment: Ну вы же где-то эти ящики сохраняете. Предположу что в БД. Если ящики могут быть также произвольного формата. Поставьте на user.email unique ключ. 
Если же в системе есть только сгенерированные ящики, то берите в качестве идентификатора user.id, а если у пользователя может быть несоклько ящиков, то ключ из смежной таблицы.

Comment: я их еще не сохраняю, для того что бы сохранить его нужно создать, так вот вопрос и заключается в том - "как создать ящик?"

Comment: @user193361, *"как создать ящик?"* — ответ на этот вопрос целиком и полностью зависит от выбранного набора программ, занимающихся приёмом/отправкой/хранением писем, и их конфигурации. обратитесь за подробностями к администратору вашего сервера.

Comment: @user193361, Про транзакции в БД слышали? Вначале создаёте запись в БД, получаете ID, потом создаете ящик с таким ID, и если вдруг что-то пошло не так. То делаете rollback транзакции. Ящика нет, в базе тоже ничего нет. AutoIncrement кстати увеличится вне зависимости от успеха транзакции. Поэтому можно даже не следить за уникальностью.

Comment: Ninazu, я знаю как с базой данных работать, вопрос в другом как этот ящик создать? какой командой?

Comment: @user193361, "командой" INSERT. В чём конкретно вопрос? Пишете же, что знаете как с базой работать. Или не знаете что конкретно туда писать? Ну так посмотрите в конфигурации почтового сервера что он из базы считывает, из каких таблиц. Создаёте в базе, которую использует почтовый сервер (если он базу использует) запись о ящике, пароле. Если почтовый сервер не умеет сам - то создаёте так же и каталог для этого ящика в нужном месте с нужными правами/владельцем. Вот и будет вам созданный ящик.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть закрыт, чтобы автор мог уточнить детали вопроса. На текущий момент совершенно непонятно, что за IMAP сервер и где он хранит пользователей. Может быть, в текстовых файлах? Может быть в mysql-базе? Это какой-то известный сервер, самопальный скрипт, что?? Топикстартер не знает -- а мы тем более, телепатов нет.